# Adjust font size to fit html element

Tags: html, text, font-size

Is there any way to adjust automatically the font size for a random text to fill the entire screen without wrapping? I am looking to ensure the visibility of all lines without allowing long text lines to wrap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        html, body{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .center {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 75px;  /* At 75px text fits the entire screen at 1920x1080  */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <p>
            Take this kiss upon the brow!<br>
            And, in parting from you now,<br>
            Thus much let me avow —<br>
            You are not wrong, who deem<br>
            That my days have been a dream;<br>
            Yet if hope has flown away<br>
            In a night, or in a day,<br>
            In a vision, or in none,<br>
            Is it therefore the less gone?<br>
            All that we see or seem<br>
            Is but a dream within a dream.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use JS to calculate font size

Comment: Do a calculation like this:
font size = screenwidth/(1920/75);

Comment: It won't work such calculation for any random text, 75px font-size looks good for the current text.